# How to send binary image data to self organizing map

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, som

I have taken a scanned image with characters, cropped the characters and stored them in a matrix.

```
X={}; 
Y={};
for cnt = 1:50
    rectangle('position',box(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
    X{cnt}=imcrop(I, box(:,cnt));
    Y{cnt}=im2bw(X{cnt});
 end
```

Here, box has the coordinates of the rectangle. I want to use Y as input to `newsom` to create a self organizing map. But i get the error:

> net=newsom(Y', [10,1])
> ??? Error using ==> cat
> CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
>
> Error in ==> cell2mat at 89
> m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});
>
> Error in ==> newsom>new_6p0 at 72
> if isa(p,'cell'), p = cell2mat(p); end
>
> Error in ==> newsom at 58
> net = new_6p0(varargin{:});

The images formed have different dimensions(12x6, 15x12 etc).
Can anyone tell me how I rectify my approach so that `newsom` gets the data of 50 binary images?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `newsom`, so am sure if this would affect the algorithm's output, but you could zero-pad all the images so that they are the same size as the largest image in the set.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `newsom` you need all your inputs to have the same size. You can achieve that using `imresize`

```
n = 50;
sz = [20 20]; this would be the size of ALL inputs
X = cell(1,n); % pre-allocate outputs, this is good practice
Y = cell(1,n);
for cnt = 1:50
    rectangle('position',box(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
    X{cnt}=imcrop(I, box(:,cnt));
    newSize = imresize( X{cnt}, sz, 'bicubic' ); % resize to the predefined size
    Y{cnt}=im2bw(newSize); % do binarization AFTER resizing!
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got rid of that problem. However, there is a new problem:
    >> net=newsom(Y,[10,1])
    ??? Error using ==> newsom>new_6p0 at 76
    Inputs are not a matrix or cell array with a single matrix.

    Error in ==> newsom at 58
    net = new_6p0(varargin{:});

I tried cell2mat but thats not the solution either.

Comment: @YashUpadhyay - I'm soory , but I am not too familiar with SOM. try converting your binary images to doubles (if they are logical).